# Passing parameters to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically generating an image as shown below. How can I pass parameters to the `ImageGen.aspx` code from `Default.aspx` so that the image can be constructed based on that.

```
  //File:ImageGen.aspx
    public partial class ImageGen: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(800, 400);
            //Code to generate image
            image.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

This image is displayed by:

```
 //File: Default.aspx
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ImageGen.aspx";
 }
```

Comment: I assume someone (not me) downvoted cause it is a very common question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass values to page using query string parameters i.e. in `default.aspx` call image generator page:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ImageGen.aspx?imageId=1";
```

and in Page_Load method of `ImageGen.aspx` retrieve this using

```
string imageId = Request.QueryString["imageId"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to read about  [**State Maintenance in ASP.NET**](http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_676.aspx)

Right now for your case 
Make use of Request query stirng that it

```
 //File: Default.aspx
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ImageGen.aspx?id=1";
 }
```

in second code use it

```
 //File:ImageGen.aspx
    public partial class ImageGen: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(800, 400);
            //Code to generate image
            image.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```